# CSS compatibility with Chrome browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I designed this basic web page which appears perfectly fine in IE and Firefox but not in Chrome.

[URL to the demo web page](http://myimplantdirect.com/Default.aspx)
You should not see the yellow color on top of the navigation. If you check the web page in different browsers, you will see what I am referring to.

Thank you,

Comment: People should not have to open your page in every browser to try to figure out your problem.  You should clearly describe your problem and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Sparky672: I already tested the website in all different browses. They are fine except for Chrome. That is why I mentioned I only have issue with Chrome.

Comment: You totally missed the point.  Your description of the problem is severely lacking.  Browser is also spelled with an "R" at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems lies with a#NavigationMenu_SkipLink, which contains a 1x1 image.
floating the anchor solves the problem for me and has no side-effects on your layout in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks Samuel. I tried this and still have problem with Chrome:

Comment: Samuel was right. Just try putting `display:none` in firebug or dev tools on that link `a#NavigationMenu_SkipLink` and you'll see your problem is solved.

Comment: @Fawadafr i guess a line of your comment got missing. I applied `float: left;` to the anchor. what did you do and what result do you see?

Comment: Thank you Samuel and elclanrs. Your help is really appreciated. I was able to find the fix.

Comment: @Fawadafr please take your time to rewrite the question to narrow down the problem so others have an chance to get rid of the same problem!